# how to access the different nodes of my simulation in OMNet++?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I want to get nodes of the network simulation and I found this piece of code:

```
int nodeID = getId();
cModule* parent = getParentModule();
cModule* module;
this->num_nodes = parent->par("numHosts");
for(int i = 1; i <= simulation.getLastModuleId(); i++)
    {
        module = simulation.getModule(i);
        if (module->getId() != nodeID)
        {
             // Some code
        }
    }
```

But when I try to compile it I have the error:

> use of an undeclared identifier for "simulation".

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the beginning of your code:

```
auto simulation = getSimulation();
```

and for `simulation` change dot operators into arrows, i.e.:

```
simulation->getLastModuleId() 
simulation->getModule(i)
```